# NRI Feelacing for a European coutry outside India

Tags: taxes, india, non-resident, income

Does a **Non Resident Indian** freelancing for an European company , but getting paid in Indian account, have to pay Indian Income tax.

Comment: You have to pay tax in the country you are resident in. If you are registered resident at country X, you pay tax there even if you put your income in your Indian account, However the indian tax authority shouldn't tax you because your money is already taxed, there are double taxation rules in Europe for example that prevent you from paying tax twice.

Answer (score 2):

A non resident Indian can be paid in India in NRE account and there is no tax liability in India

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you need to pay tax since you are getting paid through Indian account.
If you are staying outside India or a non-resident you can open an NRI Account and get paid through it is a better option.